# Copy & rename file using .bat file language?

Tags: batch-processing, batch-file, batch-rename

I want to make a .bat to copy & rename a file multiple times. I want to have a list of names, and an original file, then I want to copy that file and rename it for each name on the list.

**How I can do this using a .bat file?**

*Also is it possible to run winrar fromthe .bat to .rar or .zip every file after copying/renaming?*

Example:

```
$file = "file.tmpl";
$names = "name1, name2, name3, nameetc";
foreach( $names as $name) {
    copy $file; //to avoid deleting the original
    rename $file to $name;
    zip $name; //I dont really need this but if its easy to do i will like to use it
}
```

So I start with a file.tmpl and I end up with 4 more files (which are a duplicate of file.tmpl) called name1, name2, name3, nameetc.

*The example is not a real coding lang, I used a sort of php sintax because is the language I know more.*

Comment: If you got xargs, that would make your like much easier.

Comment: I don't really understand what you want to do. Can you make an example?

Comment: I added an example.

I would use xargs but I am on win, is it available for windows?

Comment: FWIW, http://ss64.com/nt/ is a great reference for Windows shell commands, I still use it a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do the file names need to be in a string list?

If you can name them in a separate file, like so,

```
name-one.pdf
name-two.pdf
name-three.pdf
```

then this batch file will work

```
SET source_file=%1
SET name_list_file=%2

FOR /F "usebackq delims=," %%G IN (`TYPE %name_list_file%`) DO (
    COPY %source_file% %%G
)
```

You would call it like this

```
batch-file-name source-file-name name-list-file
```

In other words, I called the batch file `make-copies.bat`, and the name file `filenames.txt`, and I used it to copy a file called `mla-play.pdf`.

```
make-copies mla-play.pdf filenames.txt
```

This also allows you to change the target name list without modifying the batch file.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, getting the names from a txt is even better.